# innermost nested JavaScript object disappears adding whole list as a property

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm a JavaScript beginner and I'm sure there is simple explanation for this but I have can't find it.  After two levels of list nesting, why am I getting [Object] and not the nested lists themselves? Thanks.

```
var obj1 = {v: 1, rest: null}    
var obj2 = {v: 2, rest: obj1}
var obj3 = {v: 3, rest: obj2}    
var obj4 = {v: 4, rest: obj3}    
var obj5 = {v: 5, rest: obj4}
```

> { v: 1, rest: null }
>
> { v: 2, rest: { v: 1, rest: null } }
>
> { v: 3, rest: { v: 2, rest: { v: 1, rest: null } } }
>
> { v: 4, rest: { v: 3, rest: { v: 2, rest: [Object] } } }
>
> { v: 5, rest: { v: 4, rest: { v: 3, rest: [Object] } } }

Comment: You are probably displaying that in the browser console, aren't you? The data is still there, its just displayed as [Object], i'm assuming just for readability purposes. :)

Comment: where do you get the result?

Comment: You're using an object `{}` and not an array `[]`. What's the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you `console.log()`'ing your output? Then it would not be suprising. Your terminal is only saving space. Probably you are scripting server-side, aren't you?

Comment: yes this is all server side and yes, console.logging the output.  Found the answer in the linked duplicate, using util: console.log(util.inspect(obj5, false, null))  Thanks everyone.